# How to use buttons to control the VBA code and breakpoint in different Modules

Tags: excel, vba

There are two buttons:

`Continue` for `Module2 Sub Main`

`Clean up` for `Module3 Sub Clean`

What I want to do is that

How to Stop at the breakpoint I showed in the picture when I click the button `Continue` if I don't add the breakpoint in the code?

I have to stop the `Module2 Sub Main,` if I want to click `Clean up` after some clicks of `Continue.`

I want to obtain those operations all in the Excel, but not go back to the VBA code again.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a **PseudoBreakPoint** macro that you insert inside your main code (which is **test3** in the example below). This PseudoBreakPoint macro would essentially run a loop that won't exit until you run the **Continue** macro by pressing the button on your sheet.

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If

Public LetsContinue as boolean

Sub Continue()
    LetsContinue = True
End Sub

Sub PseudoBreakPoint()
    LetsContinue = False
    Do
    DoEvents
    If LetsContinue = True Then
        MsgBox "The code will now resume."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Sleep (10)
    Loop
End Sub

Sub test3()
    MsgBox "Before BreakPoint"
    Call PseudoBreakPoint
    MsgBox "After BreakPoint"
End Sub
```

**Explanations:** The key here is the use of `DoEvents` which allows you to use Excel like if there were no VBA code running. The only problem with `DoEvents` is that it's a command that requires a lot of resources. That's why it is crucial to combine it with the `Sleep` function which is set to 10 milliseconds in the example above. This is enough to reduce the number of times the `DoEvents` runs from a few 1000s per second to less than 100 times per second which should not weigh too much on your CPU usage.

Comment: Thanks. `Continue` has been worked  in my code. But the `Clean up` is still not solved. I want to directly click the `Clean up` button after the some clicking of `Continue.` In your answer, I should click the `Stop` first, then click `Continue` finally,  I am allowed to click the `Clean up.` Is it possiblle to cease the main program by simply clicking the `Clean up.`

Comment: That's very strange `Clean up` works without any additional code.

Comment: I was actually doing some testing, but this seems right. This is because every time the `DoEvents` command is executed all the jobs in the queue are executed before the present code can resume. In your case, the next task in line is `Clean up` which is executed and the loop will resume after.

Answer (score 2):

You could insert the following line where you want the code to break

```
Debug.Assert False
```

**EDIT:**
However, with this method, you won't be able to run any other VBA code until you press Run (F5) in the VB Editor.

If what you want to do is put VBA in a position where it will wait for you to press `Continue` or `Clean up` to continue or run the other macro, it would require a more complicated method. Let me know in a comment if that is the case and I can edit my response accordingly.

**EDIT2:**
From you comment, I understand that you want to "Pause" the code in the middle of a loop to do some cleaning for example. In this case you will need to use `DoEvents` in combination with a cell (or a public variable could also work).

To illustrate the idea, below is an example code (using cell Z1). You will also need to create 2 buttons and link them to the 2 different macros below. The button for **StopMacro** will allow you to stop the other one (which is simply waiting for 1 second ten times).

Note that there will be a little lag before the macro stops.

```
Sub StopMacro()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Z1").Value = True
End Sub

Sub test()

Dim i As Long

For i = 0 To 9
    DoEvents
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Z1").Value = True Then
        MsgBox "The code was stopped."
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Z1").Value = False
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'The rest of your code would be here instead of this line
    Application.Wait TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now()) + 1)

Next i

End Sub
```

So, you can use the same principle inside of your loop(s) to allow to stop your code from running by pressing the *Stop button*.

However, you said that you want to *Pause* your code and resume it after. In this case, you could make your code store the progress you've made and use that as a starting point for the next time it runs, like this for example (using cell Z2):

```
Sub test2()

Dim i As Long

Dim StartingPoint  As Long
StartingPoint = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Z2").Value


For i = StartingPoint To 9

    DoEvents
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Z1").Value = True Then
        MsgBox "The code was stopped."
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Z1").Value = False

        'Before exiting, store progression (i-1)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Z2").Value = i-1

        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.Wait TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now()) + 1)
Next i

'After the loop is completed, we reset the Starting Point to its initial value
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Z2").Value = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any method that the buttons in Excel have the same effect for `F5` or `Reset` in the VBA(namely, when you click the `Continue,` the code will continue to run). Since, if you give the Excel to someone else, it's impossible to let him take some operations in VBA, he only know to click the buttons in Excel.

Comment: As I wrote, there is a way, but it's a little more complicated. So, before doing that, I just wanted to make sure that this is really needed. 
The thing is that your code doesn't really do anything before the Breakpoint, it simply defines and set the value of some variables, so I'm wondering if this would not be better to stop the macro completely based on some conditions instead.

Comment: I set the break point in the picture arbitrary, actually it is a loop, for each loop, code will create some content and clean up them before the next loop. If the your code is very long, then it's not necessary, but thanks the same.

Comment: It not that long, but it would not be worth it if you didn't have a loop as you said. I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: Sorry, you may misunderstand my point. `Continue` is used to continue the program, that means code will stop at the breakpoint until I click the  `Continue,` just same as the `F5` with the breakpoint. And `Clean up` is used that, after some times clicking on `Continue,` I want to cease here and make the Excel return to the original one, then I will `reset`  the code of `Continue` and debug the code in `Clean up,` to Clean up all the content created by the code in  `Continue` before. You can ignore the loop I said before, the clean up in the loop is not the `Clean up` in the button.